# AHK: closing a window whenever it pops up

Tags: autohotkey

I wrote an AHK script designed to copy a text from Adobe Acrobat when I press F9. It then changes it according to a regex and shows the copied text in tooltip. Additionally, I added code to automatically close an annoying window that Acrobat sometimes shows when coping a text, an infamous [There was an error while copying to Clipboard. An internal error occurred.](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/441370?start=0&tstart=0) When this window doesn't show up, the script keeps showing a tooltip, which is designed to close after a specified amount of time. I've been banging my head against the wall but I don't know how to correct this.

```
;#NoTrayIcon
#Persistent
#SingleInstance
F9::
#If WinActive("ahk_exe Acrobat.exe")
{
Clipboard:=""
send,^c
ClipWait, 1
Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "\r\n", " ")
SetTimer,CheckForMsgBox,100
CheckForMsgBox:
    IfWinExist, Adobe Acrobat
    {
        Send {Enter}
        SetTimer,CheckForMsgBox,Off
    }
;Return
If (StrLen(Clipboard) < 120)
ToolTip % Clipboard
Else
ToolTip Copied
SetTimer, ToolTipOff, -1000
return
}
#If

ToolTipOff:
ToolTip
return
```

Comment: Please clarify what is the desired behavior and what is the problem. What is the purpose of `CheckForMsgBox` in the middle of the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;#NoTrayIcon
; #Persistent ; (1)
#SingleInstance
SetTimer,CheckForMsgBox,100 ; (2)
return

#If WinActive("ahk_exe Acrobat.exe") ; (3)

F9::    
clipboard:=""
send,^c
ClipWait, 1
Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "\r\n", " ")
If (StrLen(Clipboard) < 120)
    ToolTip %Clipboard%
Else
    ToolTip Copied
SetTimer, ToolTipOff, -1000
return

#If  ; turn off context sensitivity

ToolTipOff:
ToolTip
return

CheckForMsgBox:
; ControlSend, Control, Keys, WinTitle, WinText, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText
ControlSend, , {Enter}, Adobe Acrobat  ; Close this unwanted window whenever it appears
return
```

(1) Scripts containing hotkeys, hotstrings, or any use of OnMessage() or Gui are automatically **persistent**.

(2) **SetTimer** causes a subroutine (Label) to be launched automatically and repeatedly at a specified time interval.

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm

(3) Like the #IfWin directives, **#If is positional**: it affects all hotkeys and hotstrings physically **beneath** it in the script.

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm

Comment: Works great. I really appreciate your answer and your remarks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate script that just waits and closes the copy clipboard error window.

```
Loop
{
    WinWait, Adobe Acrobat ahk_class CLASS ahk_exe EXE
    WinClose, Adobe Acrobat ahk_class CLASS ahk_exe EXE
}
```

Replace **CLASS** and **EXE** with the error window class and exe that you can get from with **Window Spy.ahk**.